# Access traffic data using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api

The following screenshot shows a traffic filter, adopted in the new Google Maps.
[image]

Can we implement the similar function using Google Maps API?

It looks like that `google.maps.TrafficLayer` can only display the live traffic data.